# How can I use the VIMRUNTIME=runtime ./build/bin/nvim to start nvim from anywhere?

Tags: runtime, zsh, windows-subsystem-for-linux, neovim

I installed neovim from source and now I dont know how to use VIMRUNTIME=runtime ./build/bin/nvim to make it start nvim from anywhere by just typing nvim. I tried adding an nvim alias to ./build/bin/nvim in my .zshrc but to no avail.

Comment: You should *install* `neovim` after you build it, rather than running it out of the temporary build directory.

Comment: I know I can install with sudo apt install neovim but it doesnt install the version I got in the build directory, it just instals the stable version, not the latest one

Comment: For example, if you ran `make build` to build it, you can probably run `make install` to install it. You can configure where it will be installed *to*, probably with the `configure` script. This should all be documented in the source distribution.

Comment: It worked, thank you. And it was in the documentation but it escaped from my attention.